# distribution measure of trajectory space in finite state irreducible Markov Chain

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-processes, markov-chains, markov-process

Consider a finite state irreducible Markov Chain $(Z_n)$ on the trajectory space $(\Omega, \mathcal{A}, \mathbb{P})$ induced by $(X,P)$ where $X$ is the state space and $P$ a stochastic matrix. For any event $A\in\mathcal{A}$, we have $\mathbb{P}(A)=\sum_{j\in X}\pi(j)\mathbb{P}(A|Z_0=j)$ where $\pi$ is an initial distribution. My question is:

1. If $A$ is a shift-invariant event, do we have $\mathbb{P}(A|Z_0=j)$ is a constant for all $j$? How does recurrence of this markov chain help us to prove it?
2. If $A$ is any event, does (1) still hold true?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: **Hints:**

**1.** If $A$ is shift invariant, then $f(j):=\Bbb P(A|Z_0)=j)$ is an invariant function; that is (viewing $f$ as a column vector) $Pf = f$.

**2.** Consider $A=\{X_0=j_0\}$, for a specific state $j_0$.

Comment: @JohnDawkins Thanks for your help! 2 is false and 1 is true since $Pf=f$ implies $f$ is a harmonic function. Since $X$ is finite, by maximal principle we have $f$ as constant. However, I didn't see how recurrence helps me here (or maybe this is not relevant).

Comment: Instead of invoking the maximum principle you could have used recurrence more explicitly: $Pf=f$ implies $P^nf = f$ for all $n=2,3,\ldots$, so $f=\lim_nP^n f=\pi(f)\cdot{\bf 1}$, where $\pi$ is the invariant distribution, $\pi(f) = \sum_{x\in X}f(x)\pi(x)$, and ${\bf 1}$ is a column of $1$s.

Comment: Would you mind me asking explicitly how did you use recurrence here? I didn't get how $\lim_{n}P^n f=\pi(f)\cdot \textbf{1}$.

Comment: In a (positive) recurrent chain, the $n$-step transition probabilities $P^n(i,j)$ will converge (as $n\to\infty$) to $\pi(j)$, where $\pi = \{\pi(j): j\in X\}$ is the unique stationary distribution. And an irreducible chain with finite state space is automatically positive recurrent.

Comment: Okay, that makes sense. Thanks a lot for your help!